# Get count of columns that are null or empty for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to check row-wise all the columns are null or empty?

I need total count for column is null or blank. Please refer below images to help you.

[image]

As result I want count = `4` for the row where StudentId=3, because four columns in that row are null.

Thank you.

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: @jarlh please refer above link.

Comment: Is that table data, or current result, or wanted result? (Also, text is better than images.)

Comment: @jarlh I want 4 count because four column is null

Comment: @jarlh is table data. and i want a result.

Comment: Are you asking for a table showing the StudentId followed by a count of how many of its columns are null, so for StudentId=1 it would be zero but for StudentId=3 it would be 4?

Comment: @OldBoyCoder exactly I want. thank for understanding my question

Comment: Have you tried `CASE WHEN Col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Col3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not probably the best approach, but it works. I created a table variable to test it, you should adopt the logic in your case:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (f1 VARCHAR(10),f2 VARCHAR(10),f3 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @tbl values(NULL,NULL,'fdgfdhfgh')

SELECT *,( CASE WHEN f1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN f2 IS NULL then       1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN f3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Nulls FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add CASEs for every column:

```
CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
...
```

Edit:

If you really need to check for empty strings, too, you can use

```
CASE WHEN col1 <> '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

`col1 <> ''` is NOT TRUE for both NULLs and empty strings.

Comment: Good answer, one point of clarity the OP asks for NULL or Empty, so ISNULL(col1, '') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + might be better.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder: In the comments OP only talks about NULLs, but I'll add a note

Comment: It's not 100% clear but the first line of his question says null or empty, I've upvoted your answer as it gets him going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (if(col1 is null,1,0) + if(col2 is null,1,0) + if(col3 is null,1,0) + if(col4 is null,1,0) + if(col5 is null,1,0) if(col6 is null,1,0) if(col7 is null,1,0)) from yourTable
```

regards.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of not hard-coding the column names, this dynamic query will work with just passing the Table name alone to the parameter `@TableName`.

I select the columns from the `sys.columns` table and manipulate the logic with [dnoeth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37387218/2451726).

```
DECLARE @TableName AS VARCHAR (256) = 'TableName';
DECLARE @SqlText AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @SqlText = @SqlText + 'CASE WHEN ISNULL(' + C.[NAME] + ', '''') = '''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + '
    FROM SYS.OBJECTS O
    JOIN SYS.COLUMNS C ON C.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID
    WHERE O.TYPE = 'U' AND O.[NAME] = @TableName 

SELECT @SqlText = 'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING (@SqlText, 1 , LEN(@SqlText) -1) + ' [NullsCounts], * FROM ' + @TableName

--PRINT @SqlText
EXEC (@SqlText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code. Its working fine with SQL server 2012:

```
DECLARE @table_A TABLE 
(StudentId int IDENTITY(1,1) , FirstName Varchar(50),LastName Varchar(50),
PhoneNumber Varchar(50),Email Varchar(50),ResidencyAddress Varchar(50),
CountyId int, CityId int)

INSERT @table_A
(
    --StudentId - this column value is auto-generated
    FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,Email,ResidencyAddress,CountyId,CityId
)
VALUES
('John','D','6052314788','john.d@gmail.com',NULL,0, 1),
(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
('Albert',NULL,'6058745962',NULL,NULL,0, 2),
('Mike','K',NULL,'mike@gmail.com',NULL,NULL, NULL)

SELECT 
    StudentId,
    CASE WHEN FirstName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN LastName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN PhoneNumber IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN Email IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN ResidencyAddress IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN CountyId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN CityId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Count of Nulls]
FROM @table_A A
```